# Rename a layout in Isotope Masonry

Tags: jquery, rename, jquery-isotope, typeerror

I want to use several isotope instances in one page.
One of these instances is a corner stamp, while the others are regular 'masonry' ones

I want to rename the cornerstamp with a new name - `homeMasonry`.

If I rename the 2 functions from http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/extending-isotope.html I get stuck with a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cols' of undefined`

These are the 2 functions

```
  $.Isotope.prototype._homeMasonryReset = function() {
    // layout-specific props
    this.masonry = {};
    this._getSegments();
    var i = this.masonry.cols;
    this.masonry.colYs = [];
    while (i--) {
      this.masonry.colYs.push( 0 );
    }

    if ( this.options.masonry.cornerStampSelector ) {
      var $cornerStamp = this.element.find( this.options.masonry.cornerStampSelector ),
          stampWidth = $cornerStamp.outerWidth(true) - ( this.element.width() % this.masonry.columnWidth ),
          cornerCols = Math.ceil( stampWidth / this.masonry.columnWidth ),
          cornerStampHeight = $cornerStamp.outerHeight(true);
      for ( i = Math.max( this.masonry.cols - cornerCols, cornerCols ); i < this.masonry.cols; i++ ) {
        this.masonry.colYs[i] = cornerStampHeight;
      }
    }
  };

    $.Isotope.prototype._homeMasonryResizeChanged = function() {
    return true;
  };
```

and the isotope call

```
 $container.isotope({
      layoutMode: 'homeMasonry',
    itemSelector: '.item',
      homeMasonry: {cornerStampSelector: '.corner'}
  });
```

I've recreated the issue with jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DQydj/133/

it appears isotope didn't like my renaming. Anyone knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to renaming the layout functions, you also have to rename the variables that refer to the original masonry object. In other words `this.masonry` would have to be changed to `this.homeMasonry`.